# OpenCV: method of measuring an objects angular displacement?

Tags: opencv

I would like to track an object using a webcam and compare every two frames together to see the changes in the angular displacement of the object. I was thinking to first extract the object from the image using background subtraction then create a bounding box around the object and then measure the angular displacement of the box. Is there any way to implement this on OpenCV?

Comment: Perhaps you can link to a few frames to better illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experimental experience in this.
Try calculating motion vectors and see the orientation and length correlations with the two frames. It will give you neat idea of type of movements eg:

1. Motion(length correlation)
2. Direction(collective direction of group of motion vectors)
3. Depth(direction and relative length of motion eg if there is depth
       then direction will be same but length of MV will be smaller).
4. Rotation and scaling can be seen by motion vectors' group behavior.

Try it and if you want more clarification, write back.
Good Luck and Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am not very familiar with the method of calculating motion vectors and I am wondering whether this will give an accurate angle reading?

Comment: Just google motion vector estimation techniques and you will find many algorithms, for difference measure use SAD(Sum of Absolute difference) although SSE(Sum of squared) is also fine.
Degree of accuracy is very nice. Be sure to choose algorithm according to your objects motion and size.
Here is a document for reference: http://goo.gl/RckOoI

Comment: For analyzing accuracy of result, first try exhaustive search and then move  to Three step/ New Three Step or Diamond whichever meets your performance s accuracy criteria.
Good Luck